# Convert ADC voltage into actual AC input voltage 230

Tags: adc

In my project, I am using an ADS1256 24-bit sensor with a RPI CM4 to read the input AC voltage and current. I just fed my AC input voltage to the filter circuit and I got an output of 0.378V, which is fed into the ADS1256 sensor. I got both positive and negative values of the voltage data points to reconstruct a original sine wave. But the output voltage reading is `0, 0.132, 0.252,..., 0.596` V for the positive half cycle and for the negative cycle it is `0, -0.142, -0.254,..., -0.354` V. So when I multiply the attenuation factor to get the actual input voltage, it gives me 230/0.596=386, implying a voltage=386*output of ADC.

My question is: Should I take the attenuation factor of 230/0.378=608V? Or should I take attenuation factor of 230/0.596=386.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming problem, as such. This looks more like an issue with understanding your device. You might do better asking on [electronics.se]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems not related to programming